# Toggling play/pause not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Getting red warnings for `{[audioPlayer pause];}`saying `Expected']'` and getting another red warning message for `[[audioPlayer play];]` saying `Expected expression`.

```
UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

UIBarButtonItem *playpause = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playpauseButton];
```

The action code:

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(UIButton *)sender
{   
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" 
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
              initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

   [fileURL release];

   [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    //[audioPlayer play];

     if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 Image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected

 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal

      {[audioPlayer pause];}

  } else {

setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected


Image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal


      [[audioPlayer play]; ]

  }


}
```

I need help in fixing this code.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire play/pause part of your method is completely invalid Objective-C. Try this instead:

```
if  ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer pause];
}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Also, you really don’t need to be recreating your audioPlayer in that method. Put it (where by “it” I mean “everything in that method between the first line and the ‘if’”) in your `-viewDidLoad` or something.

Comment: Now Play Button is showing and when i hit play button it is playing audio file and turning the play button into pause button but when i hit pause button to pause it. It is not pausing but playing the audiofile from the begining again

Answer (score 0):

try setting the delegate and checking for error:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" ofType:@"mp3"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&err];

if( err ){
    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
} else{
    //set our delegate and begin playback
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

btw, you definitely don't want to be allocing the audioPlayer every time the button is pressed, unless you check if it's nil first (for the first run through).